# Computing area of shared surface between adjacent 3D features in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst, adjacency

ArcGIS Pro currently provides the [Polygon Neighbors](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool to compute the length of the shared border between features.

I want to do the same type of calculation for (closed) 3D features, i.e. I want to calculate the area of the shared surface between two adjacent 3D features. However, I can't find a tool in ArcGIS Pro for doing this.

Does this functionality exist in ArcGIS Pro?

[image: 3D Polygons]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can use intersect 3D tool to get the boundary surfaces between adjacent polygons. However, if I specify that a "surface" is returned I get some sliver polygons whereas if I specify a "solid" is returned I get a 3D feature with a small but finite width. Based on how I created the 3D polygons there should not be any gap or overlap between features, so I would expect to be able to get a surface back. Perhaps I can use topology rules in my database or create the features in a different way to fix this overlap.
[image: 3D intersection - surface]
[image: 3D intersection - solid]

Comment: I think it would be useful to include some generated test data like a smaller cube next to and touching a larger cube to see if the expected result is found.